# unable to add panel inside another panel which already has panels as its item in Extjs 3

Tags: extjs3

```
var len = panel.items.items.length;
if(len < 15){
panel.add(this.childPanel);
panel.doLayout();
}
```

// the items inside panel remains unchanged even after performing doLayout()

Comment: Can you edit your code snippet and include how your childPanel is being defined.  Also you are only ever adding the panel if the number of childItems on your panel is less that 15, so how are these other childPanel's being added? More code please!

Comment: thanks @mindparse . The problem was with the way this.childPanel was being created. I was creating this.childPanel recursively . Since all these childPanels had the same 'Id' ,  it was not getting added to the panel.

I made the Id dynamic and the problem was resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the creation of childPanel. While creating child panel I made the id field of childPanel dynamic by giving an index to it.

```
 ChildPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    id : 'panel'+this.index,
    items : []
 });
```

This way each childPanel created will have different ids.

```
var len = panel.items.items.length;
if(len < 15){
panel.add(this.childPanel);
panel.doLayout();
}
```

this code worked perfectly after that!